# Cannot get Camera2 API touch to focus to work

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, nexus-5x

I'm unable to get the touch to focus to work properly on Camera2 API. On touching I just seem to focus for a second and then it becomes extremely blurred. The phone is a Nexus 5X. Here is my code for touch to focus.

```
private void refocus(MotionEvent event, View view){

    //Handler for autofocus callback
    CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallbackHandler = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
            super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);

            if (request.getTag() == "FOCUS_TAG") {
                //the focus trigger is complete -
                //resume repeating (preview surface will get frames), clear AF trigger
                previewRequest.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, null);
                try{
                    mSession.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequest.build(), null, null);}
                catch (Exception e){

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCaptureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, CaptureFailure failure) {
            super.onCaptureFailed(session, request, failure);
            Log.e(TAG, "Manual AF failure: " + failure); }
    };

    try {
        final Rect sensorArraySize = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraDevice.getId()).get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE);

        //Find area size
        int x = (int)(event.getX()/(float)view.getWidth() * (float)sensorArraySize.width());
        int y = (int)(event.getY()/(float)view.getHeight() * (float)sensorArraySize.height());
        final int halfTouchWidth  = 150; //(int)motionEvent.getTouchMajor(); //TODO: this doesn't represent actual touch size in pixel. Values range in [3, 10]...
        final int halfTouchHeight = 150; //(int)motionEvent.getTouchMinor();
        MeteringRectangle rect = new MeteringRectangle(Math.max(x - halfTouchWidth,  0),
                Math.max(y - halfTouchHeight, 0),
                halfTouchWidth  * 2,
                halfTouchHeight * 2,
                MeteringRectangle.METERING_WEIGHT_MAX - 1);
        mSession.stopRepeating();
        transparentLayer.drawFeedback(rect);

        //Cancel requests
        previewRequest.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL);
        previewRequest.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF);
        mSession.capture(previewRequest.build(), captureCallbackHandler, null);

        //Now add a new AF trigger with focus region
        if (isMeteringAreaAFSupported()) {
            previewRequest.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_REGIONS, new MeteringRectangle[]{rect});
        }
        previewRequest.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        previewRequest.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO);
        previewRequest.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
        previewRequest.setTag("FOCUS_TAG"); //we'll capture this later for resuming the preview

        //then we ask for a single request (not repeating!)
        mSession.capture(previewRequest.build(), captureCallbackHandler, null);

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Also have another helper function:

```
private boolean isMeteringAreaAFSupported() {
    try {
        return manager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraDevice.getId()).get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_MAX_REGIONS_AF) >= 1;
    }catch (Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

What could be the possible reason for the focus working for a brief second, and then restarting, or getting completely blurry? There is no solution that I can find which is helpful.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting AF_TRIGGER to IDLE in onCaptureCompleted - removing it entirely isn't totally well-specified.

Beyond that, it's not clear to me how you're converting from the screen touch coordinates to the camera [active array coordinates](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE) for the metering regions.  It looks like you're assuming the coordinates are identical, which isn't true.  That shouldn't cause blurriness, but will cause you to focus on a different area than you think.

You need to scale the x and y correctly (based on the current [crop region](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#SCALER_CROP_REGION) which defines the visible field of view when using digital zoom, and the active array rectangle)

Comment: Tried this, still focuses only on the most prominent object. Could you provide a short code sample of what you mean?

Comment: I updated the code to explain what I meant, could you provide a possible solution?